# How to retrieve H263/H264 data from a pcap file. 

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, h.264, vlc

I have tried tools like [videosnarf](http://ucsniff.sourceforge.net/videosnarf.html) that takes a pcap file as input and creates a raw .h264 file , which could be later encoded with ffmpeg , and finally can be played with vlc player. But videosnarf can only handle h264 data.

I'm not able to find a similar tool that can dump h263 data from a pcap file. I tried to decode h263 stream from wireshark but I have had no luck so far.

I can program in perl/python but I don't know what exact steps to follow to retrieve h263 raw data from a pcap file as I haven't played with pcap capture files before.

Comment: Seems really weird.  Why would you need it?  Chances are because it's so niche that it doesn't exist.  But the source is open!  If you need it, you should look into either adding it, or getting someone else to.

Comment: well the only reason I'm trying to retrieve the video data from pcap is to know the quality of the video transmission on the receiving end compared to the reference video used during the transmission.

Answer (score 1):

sjd,
You can try setting up a sniffer using Twisted Python library ([Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)) this would allow you to capture the raw data coming in over your network as long as you can tell Twisted what port to listen to (or listen all), and where to dump the file to, etc and then do something with that new file (like send it into ffmpeg to test saving to .mov).

You would have to generate the .sdp file for ffmpeg, so unless you automate that step of the process, it is really annoying. I am currently working on the automation portion but am struggling just as much.

I'm using EventMachine for Ruby with FFMPEG, and .sdp from SIP.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: @sjd thanks for the comment. One thing I did was just strip the RTP headers from the pcap file. It is easy to do for h263, you just need to know what your working with. You can grab the raw h263 frame data by striping the RTP header, and adding 0000 to the payload data. (rtp packetization requires stripping leading 4 zeros from frame) Here is an rtp header parser for RTP packets (you can easily get these with wireshark). https://github.com/newfront/dailyhacking/blob/master/source/media/rtp_header_parser.rb. (ruby code, but shouldn't be hard to translate to python).